# How can I have a span tightly wrap text when it is forced to newline by max-width?

Tags: css, word-wrap

Is it possible to have some text wrap at a max-width, and then have the resulting text element be as small width-wise as possible?

Currently, when my text gets longer than the max-width, it wraps and then the resulting element takes the entire max-width even though it could easily fit in a smaller width.

[Span forced to wrap, sized to max-width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Vyw.png)

[Span not forced to wrap, fits to text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irjMN.png)

Having tried several variations this is where I'm stuck:

```
<div style="text-align: left; max-width: 129px;">
  <span style="line-height: 1.2; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; display: flex; max-height: 46px; text-align: center;">Your First Project</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post more code. This is not helpful. You could use https://jsfiddle.net/ to create a replica of your scenario and add it here

Answer (score 0):

You can use `width: fit-content` and it will always size to whatever the content takes up.

Comment: Appears to have the same issue.
```
<div style="text-align: left; max-width: 129px; width: fit-content;">
  <span style="line-height: 1.2; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; display: flex; max-height: 46px; text-align: center; width: fit-content;">
    Your First Project
  </span>
</div>
```

The expanding version works, but not the becoming-smaller-when-wrap